# Apache Artemis no clientId is showing in consumer section of management-console.UI

Tags: activemq-artemis, amq, camel-jms

I am using Apache Artemis broker and Apache camel JMS component

as i am using Apache camel JMS component so here, i am listening the topic

```
    from(jms:topic:my_topic?durableSubscriptionName=dsn&clientId=testId)
            .log("......>")
```

Here i have set

```
clientId = testId
topic = my_topic
durableSubscriptionName = "dsn"
```

Now when i am using [management-console](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/latest/management-console.html).UI, so it's showing me empty client id in consumer id

[image]

In above image **Queue** = testId.dsn
where **testId** is a clientId and **dsn** is a subscription name.

also no clientId showing under client header.

why client name is no showing under client header. and also why **Queue** value is showing concatenation of clientId + subscription name

please help here, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

ActiveMQ Artemis supports lots of different protocols, but they are all implemented internally using what's called the "core" API.  Depending on the protocol you're using (e.g. AMQP, OpenWire, etc.) this may be different, but if you're using the JMS client that shipped with the broker (i.e. the "core" JMS client) then the client ID is stored in the meta-data of the "core" session on the broker. However, I don't see where the web-console actually unpacks and displays that meta-data so it looks like there is no direct way to identify the client ID. However, you can infer the client ID by looking at the first part of the queue name.

The name of the queue (which represents the subscription) is generated by the broker by concatenating the client ID and subscription name.  This is a simple way for the broker to differentiate durable subscriptions from each other and ensure that reconnecting clients are able to get to their original subscription again.

Comment: upvote: Thank you Justin your response, is there any way from management console for confirm client id of consumer?

Comment: I updated my answer with additional details to address your question.